# Angular HttpClient "Unknown Error" with .Get() Request to Azure Search API

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, httpclient

Currently facing a problem where the request to Azure Search API is returning an "Unknown error".

I got the `.Get()` request working in postman and thought it would be theoretically the same set-up in Angular using the Http Client.

```
export class AzureSearchConfigComponent implements OnInit {
synonyms: any[];
private synonymUrl = 'https://name.search.windows.net/synonymmaps?api-version=2017-11-11'
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit() 
{
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .set('api-key','xxxx-xxx-xxxxx');

this.http.get(this.synonymUrl,{headers:headers})
  .subscribe(
    repsonse => {
      console.log(repsonse);
    }
  );
}
}
```

Error message:

> ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText:
>   "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}

Postman Response:

[image]

also getting the error:

> Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Comment: As I state, it works with postman, [name] would be the name of my azure subscription, just didn't want it public.

Comment: Oh shut, I didn't see that

Comment: I've read that it's something to do with CORS, but i'm running the angular app locally on localhost:4200, tried disabling internet security on chrome but still no luck

Comment: Hmm, if it is CORS then the console should tell you that

Comment: Just posted the other error i ge tbefore the "unknown error" : Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Comment: Are you using an Admin Key or a Query Key when making this request?

Comment: An Admin Key just like I did in Postman, is this a problem?

Comment: Just from looking around a bit, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37127195/jquery-ajax-post-from-localhost-generates-no-access-control-allow-origin-hea/37144906#37144906

It looks like using an Admin Key from a client is considered insecure by azure and therefore would throw CORS errors when making requests. I believe Postman acts as a server instead of a client so making the requests there will respond correctly. You would either have to set this up in an endpoint that you request from the client or use the Query Key to make a client side request to Azure

Answer (score 1):

Turns out a temporary solution is to disable web security on google chrome, by running the following command into cmd (after locating the chrome.exe in program x86)

```
--disable-web-security --user-data-dir
```

This is because the CORS settings in chrome causes a redirect flight, I am currently also trying to host on a proxy to see if the issue can be resolved without disabling web security, will post here if successful

Comment: This is the only thing that has worked for me while testing typescript with Rider. It only seems to work with Chrome directly and not any Chrome-based browsers. I could not get Brave or Edge to work.